# Import python files in a folder with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem to import .py files in my jupyter notebook. In my environment I have a folder called 'description' where I stored four .py files (data1.py, data2.py, data3.py, data4.py). In my notebook I want to import those four files, so I run :

```
from description import *
```

Then, when I try to use it, I have an error message (as if the .py folders where not imported). I guess my request is wrong. I also tried:

```
from description.data1 import *
```

But then I get:  No module named 'description.data1'
What is the right way to import those .py files?

Thanks,